# Apply function is not working on a data-frame column

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, apply

I am trying to remove special characters like ",",".","-"(except comma) from the "Actors" column of my pandas data-frame. For this I use the apply method on the "Actors" column

```
df['Actors']= df['Actors'].apply(lambda x : x.lower().replace("[^a-zA-Z,]","",)
df['Actors'].head()
```

The output of the above snippet is shown below and we can see no special characters have been replaced:

```
1    tim robbins, morgan freeman, bob gunton, willi...
2    marlon brando, al pacino, james caan, richard ...
3    al pacino, robert duvall, diane keaton, robert...
4    christian bale, heath ledger, aaron eckhart, m...
5    martin balsam, john fiedler, lee j. cobb, e.g....
Name: Actors, dtype: object
```

But when I try resolving the above issue using the snippet below, the code works:

```
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.lower().str.replace("[^a-zA-Z,]","")
df['Actors'].head()

1    timrobbins,morganfreeman,bobgunton,williamsadler
2    marlonbrando,alpacino,jamescaan,richardscastel...
3    alpacino,robertduvall,dianekeaton,robertdeniro
4    christianbale,heathledger,aaroneckhart,michael...
5    martinbalsam,johnfiedler,leejcobb,egmarshall
Name: Actors, dtype: object
```

I want to know what is it with the apply function that it doesn't work properly while replacing characters ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `apply` on series, so `x` in the lambda is a single string of each row of the series. So, `x.lower().replace` is python `replace`. Python `replace` doesn't support regex. so it considers `"[^a-zA-Z,]"` as a whole string and it looks for that substring in each `x`. It couldn't find it so nothing got replaced.

On the other hand, Pandas `str.replace` default option is `regex=True`, so it considers `"[^a-zA-Z,]"` as a regex pattern and replaces everything properly

Comment: Thank you very much . Can you please share some documentation where the difference between replace() and .str().replace() has been illustrated or explained? Thanks again.

Comment: pandas `str.replace` docs:  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html. Notice the default `regex=True`.

Comment: docs on Python string methods. check on `replace`:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods. Note: it is python string `replace`. Panda has it own `replace` method which isn't used in your case.

Comment: `df['Actors'] = df.Actors.str.lower().str.replace('[^a-z]', '')` --- You already made it lower so no need for `[^a-zA-Z]`

Comment: @piRSquared: spot on! I focus on explaining the differences, so I didn't pay attention to the detail pattern :). thumb up!

Comment: Hi @AndyL. Could you please help me with one more problem I am facing. The link to the question is in the comment below:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773957/pandas-str-split-function-is-not-working-properly

Comment: @SarvagyaDubey: I posted an answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you do a replace on a string, formally you do `str.replace("[^a-zA-Z,]","",)`. Your sting do not contain those characters `[^a-zA-Z,]` so nothing is removed. If you prefer, python do interpret those characters as regex, but simply as string elements.

To work you should do it like this, it's just to answer your question because the preferred way to do it is with your second exemple.

```py
remove = re.compile(r"[^a-zA-Z,]")
df['Actors']= df['Actors'].apply(lambda x : re.sub(remove, "", x.lower()))
```

Herw are some documentation :

- [python str replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)
- [pandas str replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas.Series.str.replace)

Comment: You can please see the code snippet, I have used above, when I do an "apply" function using the same regex, nothing gets replaced. But when I do str().replace(), then special characters like whitespace,hyphen,fullstop get replaced. Can you please elaborate as to why this happened ? Thanks

Comment: Yes it was to illustrate my point as it was difficult to explain it :). I put documentation inside the awser.

Comment: Could you please help me with one more problem which I am facing:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58773957/pandas-str-split-function-is-not-working-properly