# Pandas str.split() function is not working properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

While trying to split the values in the "Actors" column of my dataframe, using the Pandas series str.split() function, I am getting more values than the splits I have specified:

```
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.split(",",n=3)

1      [timrobbins, morganfreeman, bobgunton, william...
2      [marlonbrando, alpacino, jamescaan, richardsca...
3      [alpacino, robertduvall, dianekeaton, robertde...
4      [christianbale, heathledger, aaroneckhart, mic...
5      [martinbalsam, johnfiedler, leejcobb, egmarshall]
```

If I try to slice the above results using the snippet below then NaNs start to appear in the results:

```
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.split(",",n=3)[:3]
df['Actors'].head()

1    [timrobbins, morganfreeman, bobgunton, william...
2    [marlonbrando, alpacino, jamescaan, richardsca...
3    [alpacino, robertduvall, dianekeaton, robertde...
4                                                  NaN
5                                                  NaN
Name: Actors, dtype: object
```

Alternatively if I try the snippet with the apply function as shown below, proper results are achieved:

```
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[:3])
df['Actors'].head()

1        [timrobbins, morganfreeman, bobgunton]
2           [marlonbrando, alpacino, jamescaan]
3         [alpacino, robertduvall, dianekeaton]
4    [christianbale, heathledger, aaroneckhart]
5         [martinbalsam, johnfiedler, leejcobb]
Name: Actors, dtype: object
```

I wanted to know why such an anomaly is happening and how to correctly use the str.split() function in this case ?

To inspect the data further you can use the below snippet of code to download the data on your own:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/uikepcpffyo2nhig52xxeevdialfl7',index_col=0)
```

Comment: You're not getting more values than you speciifed. It's just hard to tell, because comma is the delimiter between the values and also in the original data, and it doesn't show quotes around the strings. You're getting `["timrobbins", "morganfreeman", "bobgunton, william..."]`

Comment: Please try to use the following lines to download 
the data in your jupyter notebook or i-python shell once :

df = pd.read_csv('https://query.data.world/s/uikepcpffyo2nhig52xxeevdialfl7',index_col=0)
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.strip().str.lower().str.replace("[^a-zA-Z,]","")
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.split(", ",n=3)
df['Actors'].head() . This shall give you a better understanding of the data

Comment: I don't use jupyter or i-python.

Comment: Do you have any sample data available?

Comment: The point is that `n=3` doesn't mean to discard everything after the 3rd item. It means that all of them are included as part of the 3rd value.

Comment: See the example in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

Comment: I have posted the snippet to read the data. You can check that

Comment: @Barmar I have posted an answer. Please help with the explanation

Answer (score 3):

IIUC, you now wonder what is the different between `str.split(",",n=3)[:3]` and `str.split(",").str[:3]`

`str.split(",",n=3)[:3]` is splitted on `','` from left to right and splits 3 times. Output of splitting is the series where each row is a list. Next, you call `[:3]` on the output. It slices the first 3 rows of the output and returns the new series of 3 rows only.

`df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.split(",",n=3)[:3]` is series assignment. Series assignment is aligned on index. Any `df['Actors'].index` doesn't exist in the output 3-rows series will be assign as `NaN` in value. It is the reason final `df['Actors']` has only 3 rows having values and the rest is `NaN`

On `df['Actors'].str.split(",").str[:3]`, it is Pandas `Indexing with .str`. I.e, It is a built-in feature of pandas str accessor. It slice the whole series on every rows by the number passing to `[]`. You may read it more it here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#indexing-with-str. It returns same-length(same number of rows) series as the original where each row values get sliced by the number inside `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

I just found a way to get this done . As of now I don't have an explanation for it . Maybe you guys can help me with the explanation part, but this snippet actually works:

```
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.split(",").str[:3]
df['Actors'].head()

1        [timrobbins, morganfreeman, bobgunton]
2        [marlonbrando, alpacino, jamescaan]
3        [alpacino, robertduvall, dianekeaton]
4        [christianbale, heathledger, aaroneckhart]
5        [martinbalsam, johnfiedler, leejcobb]
Name: Actors, dtype: object
```

Comment: @jorijnsmit Thanks alot for you help

Comment: What's hard to explain? You split the actors string, then use a slice to get the first 3, which is what you want.

Comment: You could use `n=4` so it doesn't waste time splitting the remaining names that you're not interested in.

Comment: Alright let me tell you whats hard to get : str.split(",",3) what would this return ?? A list perhaps ??? Then on that list how come can you apply .str accessor and then slice[0:3] is my question ?

Comment: It doesn't return a list. These things are all Pandas series.

Comment: This question and answer helped me out a lot. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing with `df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.split(",", n=3)[:3]` is not slicing the string but slicing the `Series`. That's why you are getting `NaN`s starting from the fourth row. Try again with [:2] and you'll get `NaN`s from the third row.

With `.apply(lambda x: x[:n])` you do slice the actual individual strings.

Or, if you do not want to use `.apply()`, you can slice the *content* of each row instead of the series itself with:

```py
df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.split(",").str[:3]
```

Comment: The above snippet which you have mentioned is not the correct way, I was just playing around with the snippet a bit. The actual snippet :  df['Actors'] = df['Actors'].str.split(",",n=3), should split the string in the 'Actors' column into a list with 3 string elements but that isn't happening. Could you please help me with it?

Comment: Have found the answer accidentally. Please help me with the explanation.